# Linux C++ How to Programatically Get MAC address for all adapters on a LAN

Tags: c++, c, linux, mac-address, busybox

How may I use C or C++ **PROGRAM** (no command line) to get the MAC addresses (I'll take the IP addresses too if they are "free")  on my (small) local network.  It's an embedded Busybox Linux so I need a minimalist answer that hopefully doesn't require porting some library.  I don't have libnet or libpcap.  The arp cache seems to never contain anything but the MAC if the DHCP host.

Comment: Wait... you want the ARP cache?

Comment: No, not unless it get more info in it.  I'm wondering about a gratuitous arp maybe?  Or do I need a RARP?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the MAC address of LAN interface ?

Comment: I suggest you track down the source code for arp-scan and see how it does it.

Comment: Speaking of which, here's some: [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/arp-scan/1.8.1-1), a separate [Github project](https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Full source here.](https://gist.github.com/keeler/8345633)

Open `/proc/net/arp`, then read each line like this:

```
char line[500]; // Read with fgets().
char ip_address[500]; // Obviously more space than necessary, just illustrating here.
int hw_type;
int flags;
char mac_address[500];
char mask[500];
char device[500];

FILE *fp = xfopen("/proc/net/arp", "r");
fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);    // Skip the first line (column headers).
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
{
    // Read the data.
    sscanf(line, "%s 0x%x 0x%x %s %s %s\n",
          ip_address,
          &hw_type,
          &flags,
          mac_address,
          mask,
          device);

    // Do stuff with it.
}

fclose(fp);
```

This was taken straight from BusyBox's implementation of arp, in `busybox-1_21_0/networking/arp.c` directory of the [BusyBox 1.21.0 tarball](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/snapshot/busybox-1_21_0.tar.gz). Look at the `arp_show()` function in particular.

**If you're scared of C:**

The command `arp -a` should give you what you want, both MAC addresses and IP addresses.

To get all MAC addresses on a subnet, you can try

```
nmap -n -sP <subnet>
arp -a | grep -v incomplete
```

Comment: Doesn't look like C/C++ to me.  I also don't have nmap.  This is embedded linux.  Think TINY.

Comment: Doesn't look like C/C++ to me, either. :p Just throwing out ways to get what you want. Figured you wouldn't have `nmap`, but do you have `arp`? If so, did that work for you? If `arp` and `nmap` simply aren't options, you can always check out their source. I'll keep digging, see if I can turn anything else up.

Comment: look at all of those beautiful buffers to overflow... nop slide here we go!

Comment: Not intended to be a paragon of safety, just intended to illustrate how to read the data.

Comment: I do have arp, but it never seems to hold any but the one address.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the arp table contains a MAC address until it has an associated ip address...